# Creating a symmetrical matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices

> Non-square matrices:
>
> $A$ an $m × n$ matrix
>
> $x$ in $\mathbb{R^n}$, $Ax$ in $\mathbb{R^m}$
>
> $||Ax||^2 = (Ax) · (Ax) = (Ax)^T(Ax) = x ^T A ^T Ax = x ^T (A ^T A)x$.
>
> $A ^T A$ is a square symmetric matrix.

Does this that anything multiplied with $x^T$ and $x$ is automatically a symmetrical matrix? I'm kinda confused on how this process is proving symmetry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check $A^TA$ is symmetric by just taking the transpose: $(A^TA)^T = A^T (A^T)^T = A^T A$